# What's the most efficient way to farm favor with a Giant?

Tags: glitch-2011

Barring quests and badges (which aren't repeatable, so can't be farmed), the only way I know to gain [favor](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Favor) with a Giant is by donating at shrines.  I'm currently churning out [Sammiches](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Sammich) as fast as I can and dumping them into [Lem's](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Lem) shrines so that I can unlock [Better Learning III](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Better_Learning_III), but it's slow going.

Is there a more efficient way to gain favor?  The wiki page is fairly thin.  If nothing else, are there crafting recipes which offer a better favor/energy ratio?

Comment: I've noticed donating one item at a time avoids multiple items' values from being rounded down.

Comment: @antony.trupe that doesnt work for some items like elements, grain, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since favor gained is related to the value of the item donated, you'll want to find high value items that are relatively easy to get.  What items you use depends on your current skill set.

Many people swear by sparkly rock, which you can mine efficiently with Mining level 3 or 4.  You also gain gems this way, which can be extraordinarily valuable.

If you have high Animal Kinship, it is extremely profitable to gather meat and donate that directly.  Finding streets or zones with many pigs at the highest AK level can easily fill your bags with delicious and profitable meat.

Most recipes for items can't beat the cost/benefit ratio of those raw materials.  If you want to craft things for donation, I think the best method is to sell your items in auctions and then use the currants to fund acquisition of items (ie, shrine powder, plus other auction house items that generally sell for less than they're worth).

If you're interested in maximizing your shrine donations, check out Zu's thread:

http://www.glitch.com/forum/general/9667/

...which is probably the authoritative source on all things shrine related.

I'll also pimp my FavorSaver tool:

http://agent86ix.github.com/glitch/

Answer (score 6):

Dumping high-value goods in shrines (with the use of Shrine Powder) is the quickest way to *farm* favor, but if you're just interested in unlocking Better Learning III...

You receive large amounts of favor (+50 each) with Lem from exploration achievements; visiting every street in a hub, and visiting a large amount of streets, might end up being a quicker source of favor than farming up material. You can see what streets you've visited by looking in the Encyclopedia on the website, and the answer to "[Where have I been](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/where-have-i-been/31879#31879)" has a bookmarklet to facilitate this endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

I maxed out Animal Kinship and farm grain from chickens to get music boxes. Spam enter over top the chicken for 5 squeezes per chicken. I've not collected data, but it seems like every 4 or 5 chickens(20-25 squeezes) gives a music box.

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't know music boxes were obtainable via high-level chicken squeezing.  Of course, getting the highest levels of AK will require farming favor with Humbaba… :-)

Comment: @Ben true, there is a slight catch-22.

Answer (score 1):

Donating gems and powders will give you the most favor points. Gems are rare, but can be obtained by mining and digging. You can create Powders, but you'll need to have the Intermediate Admixing skill, a beaker, and some compounds to mix together.

... and you can always get these items from other people as gifts or at the auctions.