# Where have I been?

Tags: achievements, glitch-2011

I'm trying to earn my [Completist](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Badges#Completist) badges, but can't figure out how to tell where I have and haven't been.  I thought I saw a gameplay tip flash across the screen at one point about unvisited streets, but I can't find a way to see it again.  I even checked whether the [API](http://developer.glitch.com/api/) could be coaxed into telling me how many times I've visited a street, but no such luck.

There's also a complication: **I'm colorblind**.  If there's a visual difference between visited and unvisited streets, I can't see it.

So how can I figure out where I've been?

Comment: good question. I've been thinking about this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like the API supports retrieving how many times a Glitch has visited a street and the time of their last visit, but this information **is** tracked. If you look at the Encyclopedia of Locations when logged in, each street page will display this information.

So someone wrote a bookmarklet to get around it. It's [here](http://joefriedl.net/lab/bookmarklets/); drag it into your bookmarks to use it. Clicking on it will take you to the Locations page in the Encyclopedia, with a few new options. There's a link to 'check' a hub, which will step through each street in the hub and cross it out if you've been there, and besides each location it will add a link to set that location as your in-game destination.

Comment: perfect. good find.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been implemented in the game. The in game map greys out any street you have not visited, and the updated encyclopedia now shows a checkmark besides every street you visit.

Note that this does not include all locations that counts for traveller and completist achievements, such as Seam Streets and hidden floors. For those you should refer Agent86's answer on this question: [What streets have I not visited?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32594/3936)