# What streets have I not visited?

Tags: glitch-2011

I currently have visited 729 streets. I'm trying to get World-Class Traveler. The [most streets visited is 766](http://www.glitch.com/leaderboards/travellers/). I've visited [every street listed in the encyclopedia](http://www.glitch.com/locations/) using the [Glitch Location Helper](http://joefriedl.net/lab/bookmarklets/). What streets are not listed in the list of Locations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where have I been?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/where-have-i-been)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is about a different set of achievements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be of use to you:

http://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/30677390/glitch/location_list.html

Several of them don't appear to show up in the encyclopedia.

There's an active thread on the forum discussing the various locations:

http://www.glitch.com/forum/general/9830/