# How do I know how many meals I've cooked with a given utensil?

Tags: achievements, glitch-2011

In Glitch there some achievements that require you to cook __ meals with a Frying Pan (for example)

How do I know how many I've chopped, fried, blended, etc?

**Related:** [Where have I been?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/where-have-i-been)

Comment: I don't think its knowable outside of checking for any previously completed achievements in a given chain.

Comment: I would pay any amount of money to see this question migrated to [seasoned advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to tell. Potentially it might be possible for a third part script to (1) keep track of this or (2) access this info, but at this time there is none.

Comment: This is not possible with the api.

Comment: Maybe I could write a plugin that keeps track of every time you whip up a meal with a utensil, which calibrates based on past achievements, or new ones, for instance if you just got the 1009 one then it would know that and start counting from there.